# Help to me prove limit of F(X)

Tags: limits, functions, epsilon-delta

I want to prove this function,by the way find out **δ(ε**)
 
  $\lim_\limits{x\to 7}\frac{(2x^2-11x-221)}{x-7}=17$

But I don't have any idea , except if x = 17 then limit equal to 17 :D

Comment: Check if your expression is correct. When $x \to 7$ the denominator goes to zero but the numerator does not.

Comment: Are you sure. the limit is $17$.l'Hopital would give an other.

Comment: If X is 7 then 7 - 7 = 0 and you cannot have a number over 0 you would just get a maths error.

Comment: The tag ([tag:theorem-provers]) is for questions about software designed for checking formal proofs or assisting with writing them, see the [tag-wiki](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/theorem-provers/info). It is not intended for all questions which are about proofs of theorems

Answer (score 0):

Put $x=y+7$.
Then 
$2x^2-11x-221
=2(y^2+14y+49)-11(y+7)-221
=2y^2+17y-200$

This does not go to zero
with $y$
so your expression
does not have a limit.